# NullPointerException in Junits

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I started learning junits, and i am trying to mock arraylist class, but it is showing me null pointer exception.

here is my code:

```
public class MyListTest {

    @Mock
    ArrayList<String> al;
    @Test
    public void whenNotUseMockAnnotation_thenCorrect() {

        when(al.add("a")).thenReturn(true); 
        assertTrue(al.add("a"));


    }

}
```

Comment: you need to initialize the mocks. either with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` or in `@Before` method

Answer (score 2):

It's required to "start" Mockito. Actually the @Mock annotation is acting like a decorator, you need to do one of the following:

1. Annotate the JUnit test with a MockitoJUnitRunner:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyListTest
```

2. Enable Mockito programatically by MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(). You can use this one time in a @Before method of JUnit. Example:

```
@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should run your testclass with this runner `@RunWith(org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`

Comment: Oh thanks it worked. How Runwith helped me to pass this?

Comment: You're welcome. You could find your answers here : https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/junit/MockitoJUnitRunner.html